# Gunicorn: Access logs to a file instead of Stndout

Tags: django, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am using Digitalocean one click Django server deployment using below version of Python, Django and Gunicorn.

```
gunicorn (version 19.7.1)

python 2.7
```

I can't seem to figure out how to log my access logs into a file. Below is my gunicorn.service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon for Django Project
Before=nginx.service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/egre
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --name=egre --pythonpath=/home/django/egre --bind unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py --access-logfile /var/log/emperor.log eGRE.wsgi:application
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=gunicorn
User=django
Group=django


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.7.1/settings.html#logging

After following the above documentation I tried using `--access-logfile=-` which works but does not log my stndout to a file after passing a relative path the gunicorn does not restart giving an exit-code 1.

How to write logs to emperor.log?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try like this using [django's logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/logger/gunicorn_access.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Gunicorn starts and stops after copy pasting the above snippet. I added the file in the above filename location. Could you tell what could I be missing? As without executing the gunicorn file and just executing ExecStart command everything works fine. I am missing something related to User?

Comment: does it show any errors? Also, do you have permission to write logs in those directory?

Comment: Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-02-05 21:35:25 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 28360 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --name=egre --pythonpath=/home/django/egre --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --config /etc/gunicorn
 Main PID: 28360 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Well, that error is not very helpful. I am assuming its a file write permission issue(not sure though).